# How to add html tag with class name in xml block in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, xml, wishlist

Wishlist index index xml . I use this file in theme. I try

```
<container name="div.test" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test-class" after="-">
<block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/price.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.wishlist">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">wishlist_configured_price</argument>
                                <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                                <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_list</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" cacheable="false"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="allowedQuantityViewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Wishlist\ViewModel\AllowedQuantity</argument>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add to Cart</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </block>
</container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `referenceContainer` inside which you want to display your div container.

Update your overriden file `wishlist_index_index.xml` inside theme:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="wishlist_head_components" template="Magento_Wishlist::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist" name="customer.wishlist" template="Magento_Wishlist::view.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="wishlist_item_pager"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Rss\Link" name="wishlist.rss.link" template="Magento_Wishlist::rss/wishlist.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Items" name="customer.wishlist.items" as="items" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/list.phtml" cacheable="false">
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Image" name="customer.wishlist.item.image" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/image.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Info" name="customer.wishlist.item.name" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/name.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column" name="customer.wishlist.item.review" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/review.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.price" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/price.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.render.wishlist">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                                <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">wishlist_configured_price</argument>
                                <argument name="price_label" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
                                <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_list</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Options" name="customer.wishlist.item.options" cacheable="false"/>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.inner" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-inner</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Comment" name="customer.wishlist.item.comment" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/comment.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product Details and Comment</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart" name="customer.wishlist.item.cart" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="allowedQuantityViewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Wishlist\ViewModel\AllowedQuantity</argument>
                                <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add to Cart</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>

                        <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Actions" name="customer.wishlist.item.actions" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/actions.phtml" cacheable="false">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-item-actions</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Edit" name="customer.wishlist.item.edit" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/edit.phtml" before="-" cacheable="false"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Remove" name="customer.wishlist.item.remove" template="Magento_Wishlist::item/column/remove.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <container name="customer.wishlist.buttons" as="control_buttons" label="Wishlist Control Buttons">
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.update" template="Magento_Wishlist::button/update.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.share" template="Magento_Wishlist::button/share.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Button" name="customer.wishlist.button.toCart" template="Magento_Wishlist::button/tocart.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
                </container>
                <container name="div.test" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test-class" after="customer.wishlist.buttons">
                    <move element="customer.wishlist.item.price" destination="div.test" as="new.customer.wishlist.item.price" after="-"/>
                    <move element="customer.wishlist.item.options" destination="div.test" as="new.customer.wishlist.item.options" after="new.customer.wishlist.item.price"/>
                    <move element="customer.wishlist.item.cart" destination="div.test" as="new.customer.wishlist.item.cart" after="new.customer.wishlist.item.options"/>
                </container>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: can you please check the updated answer

Comment: do not show this div tag.

Comment: Updated again please check now

Comment: same output. not showing

Answer (score 0):

Besides declaring `htmlClass` and `htmlTag` attributes, you also need to add at least a block inside the container to allow Magento to render your container.

For example:

```
<container name="div.test" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="test-class" after="-">
    <block name="block.test" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Test" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml"/>
</container>
```

Your current blocks have issues, the page will throw the error:

> Error: Call to a member function getProduct() on null in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist/Item/Column/Cart.php:69
> #0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render.php(75): Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist\Item\Column\Cart->getProductItem()
> #1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Render.php(56): Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render->getProduct()
> #2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1117): Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render->_toHtml()